# PHP Session Lost when accessing a page through CURL

Tags: php, session, curl

I was accessing a page `set.php` on a server which sets a session value on that server. I could see the value in the session by running another script `get.php`.

Here is my problem: I run the script `set.php` from my IP and tried to run `get.php` through a a cURL script, but I cannot see the value set in the session. While accessing the page through cURL, I cant see the value in the session. Why?

Comment: Use *cookie jar* to save the cookie session in a file, note that you won't see it in the browser since you aren't sending it.

Comment: You have to use `Cookie` for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187985/php-curl-preserve-session

Comment: See my 2 urls are xample.com/set.php and xample.com/get.php I embed the xample.com/set.php using an iframe, it sets a session value, when i run xample.com/get.php on browser it prints . But if i run xample.com/get.php through curl, nothing displays