# How to grab a URL with the current session?

Tags: drupal, curl

In Drupal I am logged in as a user. If I use my super cool drupal curl function:

```
function formtocart_graburl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$output = curl_exec($ch);  
return $output;
}
```

to grab any url, it returns the content as if though I'm not logged in. How can I force CURL to think I am logged in as the user calling this function?

**UPDATE**

Assume the following:

1. I am logged in at http://mydmomain.com/drupal
2. I can access http://mydmomain.com/drupal/admin as I am an admin user
3. When I am logged in, I try to grab the URL: http://mydmomain.com/drupal/admin, but it returns content that says I am not logged in.
4. I would like curl to think I am logged in as the user I am logged into on Drupal

I assume the solution has something to do with grabbing the cookie or the sessions details and passing it to the curl function somehow?

Comment: Pls elaborate further wht u are trying to do.  Why are u using curl ?

Comment: pls print the data you want to get with curl and what do you want to do with it. You might be able to use node_view and node_render.

Comment: you probably need to set cookie auth for curl query because you open another php session as anonymous user. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187985/php-curl-preserve-session .. bottom solution looks like a answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question, at least the way it's worded, is a little confused on how users work with respect to called functions and being logged into a Drupal site; to wit, the difference between application level users and server level users.

Generally speaking, you don't run code such as that *as* a user in Drupal. While you could assign permission to execute a Drupal hook that contains that function, it won't execute *as* that user but the user Drupal itself is running as, for example www-data.

Reading between the lines here, if you really just want to give access control rights over that code to Drupal's ACL system, then you should read up on the API documentation for hook_permission():

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7

If you don't explicitly implement hook_permission, then yes, that would allow the function to be run 'anonymously' as you seem to be saying.